# How to make Rect of irregular shape sprite?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocos2d-iphone

I used masking for breaking an image as the below mention pattern now its breaking in different pieces but now i have one issue to make the Rect of each pieces, i need to drag the broken pieces and to adjust at correct position so that i can make again actual images. To drag and put at right positing i need to make Rect but i am not getting idea how to make Rect of this irregular shape, I will be very thankful to you, any idea or code to make rect . My previous Question is:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27650/how-do-i-break-an-image-into-6-or-8-pieces-of-different-shapes/27655#comment53300_27655

Answer (score 0):

Why you want to make rect of broken image ? If you want to move the images on touch then it'll not require any rect.The only reason for using Rect of irregular shapes are for sake of collision detection from right part of image.If this is the reason for making cgrect of broken images you can use boundingBox of sprites with pixel perfect collision.

If this is the case in can give you pixel perfect collision detection code.